# Reusing bootstrap weights

Tags: bootstrap

I am doing 3 bootstrapping one with 100 replicates, one with 200 replicates, and one with 500 replicates.

Is it valid if I generate 500 replicates and use first 100, and 200, and all of them (500) to do three bootstrapping that I was going to do?
Or should I create separate 100, 200, 500 replicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. The correlation between the sets will no longer be ~$\frac{2}{3}$ as it is in common bootstrapping, but it is on you to decide if this is a problem.